# DOMDocument returns 500 when using getAttribute()

Tags: php, nginx, domdocument

I have an html iframe code and I want to get the href value of the first a tag. I have this php code

```
<?php
$iframe_input=$_GET["code"];
$doc_url = new DOMDocument();
@$doc_url->loadHTML($iframe_input);

$iframe_links = $doc_url->getElementsByTagName('a');
$iframe_link = $iframe_links[0]->getAttribute('href');

echo $iframe_link;
?>
```

When I run it locally on xampp everything is ok. But when I run it on a nginx webserver (digitalocean), I get an HTTP 500.

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

FYI If I remove`$iframe_link = $iframe_links[0]->getAttribute('href');`, it doesn't return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive that error it's because on your server you have an older version of PHP.

You can use `DOMNodeList` as array only from version 5.6 . Check [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67949)

If you want to work on your server that have an older version you need to get the item from element 0 using the method [`item()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) like this:

```
$iframe_links->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: I tried your code and it gives an HTTP 500. Btw I updated the thread with the error from the log file

Comment: @DimitriosStefos I updated my answer to reflect the error that you reported. Hope now will work.

Comment: I updated my php to php5.6-fpm and it works! Thanks a lot Daniel!